# Text on webpage becomes huge when viewed through Firefox on Android

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

I have the following content on my site:

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 17px; text-align: left;">
        <p>lorem ipsum etc etc</p>
</div>
```

As you see, the font size is set at 11px. Of course it displays as 11px in all browsers, because there's no reason for it not to. Looking at "inspect element" there are no conflicting styles or anything. The inline `font-size: 11px;` is all there is.

However, for some reason I can't fathom, the text is huge in Firefox on Android. And I mean huge, to the extent that it ruins the layout of the page.

At first I thought it may be a problematic setting in my Firefox, but no. I tried on several devices and it's the same thing. There is an option in the browser to adjust the text size, as well as a 'font inflation' option, but even setting it to the smallest size, this paragraph remains gigantic.

Most of the site looks OK, it's this paragraph and a few others that are blown out of proportion. They all have set font sizes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't be sure unless i experiment something on your site. These could be helpful i hope. **Viewport meta tag**
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it better with a link to your css file where these font styles are being handled but without seeing that I could suggest you try em units and see if you have any more luck.

An explantion + example of em being used in CSS -

[EM units for font size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_em)

Other than that it could be a problem with font-family not being supported in the same way across all browsers or possibly some browser specific styles using moz (for firefox) and webkit (for chrome) being applied.